# Webform add data along with submitted values

Tags: 6, hooks, webforms, forms

I'm using Webform 6x 3.11 and have passed a *nodeID* into a hidden field called `hidden_key`. I have created a custom module to implement `hook_form_alter()` whereby I am trying to add additional data (along with the data that is being submitted) to the submission results.

This additional data is based on some calculations performed on the value in the hidden field, ie: getting some details about the node based on the *nodeID*. Here's what I currently have:

```
<?php
    function custom_form_proc_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_33') {
            $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_form_proc_submit';
        }
    }

    function custom_form_proc_submit($form, &$form_state) {
        $node = node_load($form_state['values']['hidden_key']);
        $pool_title = $node->title;
        $pool_category = $node->field_category[0]['value'];

        // ?????
    }
?>
```

Where you see my `?????` is where I am stuck. Along with whatever data gets submitted with the form, I would like to add these 2 custom fields to the submission results so that it looks like:

**Fullname:** Mr So-and-So
**Email Address:** someone@test.com
**Pool Category:** `$pool_category`
**Pool Title:** `$pool_title`
**Availability:** Yes

I would really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:** okay, after playing around a bit, this was actually easy and much simpler than I anticipated.

Firstly, instead of passing the nodeID to the hidden field, I simply went with this option for those that are similarly stuck.

```
function custom_form_proc_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_33') {
        $node = node_load($_GET["n"]);
        $form['submitted']['pool_title']['#default_value'] = $node->title;
    }
}
```

When the form renders, my  disabled textfield `pool_title` is automatically populated, and submitted along with the results. Something tells me this isn't as simple as this, but if anyone foresees an issue with this approach (like with other validation/email submission/data store

Comment: Are you passing `$_GET["n"]` manually? (Sorry if I'm missing something.) The only disadvantage I can see to this approach is that a malicious user could change the value for `pool_title` that gets returned by the browser. Also, there's no access checks on the `node_load` which could potentially lead to unauthorised access.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In the full-view of a specific content-type's node, a link is added to the bottom of the content (generated from views_attach display), which is where `$_GET['n']` is generated. Upon clicking the link (`www.mysite.com/forms/participate?n=67`) the user will be redirected to the form. I've handled validation by overriding my `webform-node-33.tpl.php` to check the content-type using `node_load` before rendering the form, else the user gets a nasty _Access prohibited_ message. `pool_title` is also a disabled field that the user can't tamper with.

Answer (score 4):

I think the simplest way to do it would be to create another hidden field to store the calculated value. Then you can use [`hook_webform_submission_presave()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--webform--webform_hooks.php/function/hook_webform_submission_presave/6) to do the calculation and store the result in `$submission->data[$cid]` where `$cid` is the component ID of the destination component.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. But I think it would not work as well. As the hook_webform_submission_presave() does not pass $submission as reference as it should. For this webform will have to fix.

Comment: hi, my understanding is that you might as well be using `hook_form_alter()` instead of unnecessarily implementing `hook_webform_submission_presave()`. I need for the form field to be altered before it gets submitted. Anyway, I managed to solve it, but can only post my answer in an hour (low rep), so stick around and tell me if you foresee any problems with my approach.

Comment: @Shoaib Nawaz - I think it _does_ pass `$submission` as a reference (see link in the answer). It wouldn't be a very good presave hook if it didn't let you alter the submissions!

Answer (score 3):

For webform submission it is best to use `hook_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission)`.
`$submission->data` will contain all the submitted values arranged against form components ids.

See my implementation how I arranged a webform as user register form.

```
function user_register_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission){
// Load information about form components
$comps = $node->webform['components'];
$fields = array();

//Extract the component info to get form_key=>cid to resolve relation
foreach($comps as $cid => $comp_info){
    $fields[$comp_info['form_key']] = $cid;
}

// Load the submitted data (field values)
$data = $submission->data;

//Prepare a user info
$user = array(
    'mail' => $data[$fields['mail']]['value'][0],
    'name' => $data[$fields['name']]['value'][0],
    'pass' => user_password(8),
    'status' => 1,
    'init' => $data[$fields['mail']]['value'][0],
    'roles' => array(2, 3),
);

$account = user_save(null, $user);  
}
```

Comment: Hi Shoaib. Sorry Im a bit of newbie when it comes to Drupal custom dev. Could you explain a bit more? I'm really trying to grasp what you have provided in the context of what I'm trying to achieve. What do I need to do to send this custom array to the webform result table in the db? thanks for your time!

Comment: @Shoaib I believe `hook_webform_submission_insert` is called _after_ saving to the db, so I'm not sure it would really fit maGz's situation.

Comment: @Andy you are right.

Comment: I got this working, but can only submit my answer in another 1 hour due to my low rep. Thanks for all the help though